# Check the largest count then proceed with a insert in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Hi I have a question but before that here is my code

```
get_count : LOOP

    INSERT INTO tbl1 values (col1,col2) VALUES (va1,va2);

    INSERT INTO tbl2 values (col1,col2) VALUES (va1,va2);

END LOOP : get_col;
```

Thats my example lets assume that during the loop there are chances that the value between two tables are not the same for example like this.

[image]

My target is to add dummy data or even just a blank like this.

[image]

Is it possible to find who is the largest count between 2 tables?
like `table1_count = SELECT count(*) FROM tbl1` or `tbl2`
then after finding it fill up the vacants by proceeding it with `INSERT`

to make it short I want is to fill up blank spaces for those tables who has incomplete values just like above image.

like this code

```
get_count : LOOP

    INSERT INTO tbl1 values (col1,col2) VALUES (va1,va2);

    INSERT INTO tbl2 values (col1,col2) VALUES (va1,va2);

    /* After inserting check who has the largest value */

    /* Insert blank data to make both tables same size*/

END LOOP : get_col;
```

I hope someone help me with this one. thnx

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: how about insert cursor on tables & check if other table has more records then add blank data in the table.

Comment: Sounds quite good i hope you can give me atleast an example code.

Comment: do table1 and table2 have an id column, do you know what is going to be inserted into table1 and table2 before the insert to table1?

Comment: both table1 and 2 has an id cause later on after the stored procedure i will join them.  I know what to be inserted on both tables because both of them will come on `cursor` query

Comment: The only thing i need to know is to find who has the largest count between 2 inserts then minus them to the current length then what will left will act as blank that will be inserred

Comment: Hi guys still no idea to figure this out?